# Integral over hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

I am trying to find the force acting on a charged hemispherical shell from the other half of the sphere. I have an equation for force, but when trying to find only the axial forces (since forces in the other directions cancel) why would I integrate over $\sin\theta \cos\theta d\theta$ from 0 to $\pi/2$? what does that integral represent?

Comment: I think why is how, mistype,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2\sin(\theta)\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\phi$ is the area element on the sphere.  $\theta$ is the polar angle, so $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ defines the upper hemisphere.  The extra $\cos(\theta)$ arises because you are taking the $\hat z$ component of the force.